# The connection was not closed. The connection's current state is connecting. Using ajax call with Repository pattern

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, design-patterns, repository-pattern

I am doing a simple ajax call to a controller from the view to get a drop down list on a text value changed.

Ajax code is simple it just post a id to the controller, after checking null or empty with proper validation.

On controller i am using the repository pattern to get the list of the client associated with that id. My controller codes look like this.

```
 public class CallCenterController : Controller
{
    private readonly IUnitOfWork _unitOfWork;
    private readonly ISubCompanyService _repoCompanyService;
    public CallCenterController(IUnitOfWork unitOfWork, ISubCompanyService repoCompanyService)
    {
        _unitOfWork = unitOfWork;
        _repoCompanyService = repoCompanyService;
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult GetLocationsByClient(int? clientID = 0)
    {
        try
        {
            List<SelectListItem> locs = new List<SelectListItem>();
            IEnumerable<SelectListItem> locations = null;

            var client = _repoCompanyService.GetCompanyListByClientID(clientID);

            if (client != null)
            {
                locations = _repoLocationService.GetActiveLocationByCompanyID(client.sub_company_id).ToList().Select(
                           s => new SelectListItem
                           {
                               Text = s.name + " - " + s.address1 + " - " + s.city + " - " + s.state,
                               Value = s.location_id.ToString()
                           });
                locs.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "--Select--", Value = "0" });
                foreach (var loc in locations)
                {
                    locs.Add(loc);
                }
                return Json(new SelectList(locs, "Value", "Text"));
            }

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Elmah.ErrorSignal.FromCurrentContext().Raise(ex);
        }

        return Json(new SelectList("", "Value", "Text"));
    }
 }
```

On Service i am doing this

```
 public class SubCompanyService : ISubCompanyService
 {
    private IUnitOfWork _unitOfWork;
    private GenericRepository<sub_company> _reposubCompany;

    public SubCompanyService(
    IUnitOfWork unitOfWork,
    GenericRepository<sub_company> reposubCompany)

    public sub_company GetCompanyListByClientID(int? ClientID)
    {
        return _reposubCompany.Get(x => x.client_id == ClientID);
    }
}
```

IUnitOfWork Class

```
public interface IUnitOfWork : IDisposable
{
    HiringManagerEntities DbContext { get; }
    void Commit();
}
```

Unit of Work Class.

```
public class UnitOfWork : IUnitOfWork
{
    private HiringManagerEntities dbContext;

    public HiringManagerEntities DbContext
    {
        get
        {
            if (dbContext == null)
            {
                dbContext = new HiringManagerEntities();
                dbContext.Database.CommandTimeout = 300;
            }
            return dbContext;
        }
    }
    public void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (disposing)
        {
            if (dbContext != null)
            {
                dbContext.Dispose();
                dbContext = null;
            }
        }
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        Dispose(true);
        GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    }
}
```

Generic Repository:

```
    public class GenericRepository<T> : IGenericRepository<T> where T : class
{
    protected HiringManagerEntities DbContext;
    private readonly IDbSet<T> dbSet;
    public GenericRepository(IUnitOfWork unitOfWork)
    {
        this.DbContext = unitOfWork.DbContext;
        dbSet = DbContext.Set<T>();
    }
}
```

I am Using Unity for IOC and my code to register is

> ```
>  container.RegisterType<IUnitOfWork, UnitOfWork>(new HierarchicalLifetimeManager());
>  container.RegisterType<ISubCompanyService, SubCompanyService>();
> ```

On Local machine when i am debugging the code it never produces any error or exception but during the production there is always a exception on the log.

Exception shows always at this line of code:

> HMS.ServiceLayers.ServiceRepository.SubCompanyService.GetCompanyListByClientID(Nullable`1
>   ClientID)

Please suggest me for any possible work around for this and please let me know if I should change my approach from the outset to solve this problem.

Comment: You are passing a nullable int. Do you really need that? I can't see you are validating for null types. You may try changing the nullable int to a regular int.

Comment: How are you managing the creation of the DbContext? The error is indicating that the context is being shared.

Comment: i am always validating the id on the client side every time before making a ajax call. If the id is null or empty the ajax call is never made. and the Client id is a nullable  int on the database too.

Comment: @AydinAdn i have edited my question. Hope this will give you how i am doing the creation of DbContext.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is right here:

```
container.RegisterType<IUnitOfWork, UnitOfWork>(new HierarchicalLifetimeManager());
```

Change it to:

```
container.RegisterType<IUnitOfWork, UnitOfWork>(new PerRequestLifetimeManager());
```

Also why not allow Unity to take care of the DbContext as well, you can inject it into the UnitOfWork class above instead of allowing it to manage it on its own.

On a side note, I'd post this to code review too, there's other issues with the code that falls outside the scope of the question.

Comment: Regarding your second suggestion, can you suggest me some link or articles to move ahead (as I am a newbie to this type of problem)?

Comment: Actually theres another issue, IUnitOfWork doesnt implement IDisposable, the code above wont be much use because Unity is unable to dispose of the connection. You need to change it so that the DbContext is managed by Unity, and so that you're not creating an instance of it like you're in UnitOfWork. Ill post an example in a bit

Comment: Sorry i forgot to add the IUnitOFWork class earlier. Here i had implement the IDisposable class.

Comment: Ok, in that case yes it should work. I would still go ahead and post this to the CodeReview section, but to keep it short, your use of ToList() on a DbSet, is worrisome performance wise (what happens when you have thousands of records? The UnitOfWork could have been a lot cleaner if it was implemented as an Attribute that you could apply to each controller action. The ControllerAction GetLocationsByClientId is setup as a POST request but there's no POST parameters. UnitOfWork is creating its own DbContext when Unity should be the sole entity doing that.

Comment: But while i tried PerRequestLifetimeManager() in the UnityRegister class.
It produces the error.

Exception is: InvalidOperationException - The PerRequestLifetimeManager can only be used in the context of an HTTP request. Possible causes for this error are using the lifetime manager on a non-ASP.NET application, or using it in a thread that is not associated with the appropriate synchronization context.

Comment: On the ControllerAction Here i have post only a integer using the Ajax Post so i don't need a model object as a parameter. 

If you mean ToList() in SelectListItem. Thank you for noting me that. I will be changing the code.

Comment: You may not technically need it. but it's best practice. The method is named starting with the word "Get", the method doesn't persist any data to the backend either for it to be a POST request. It's just retrieving data. The error mentioned is telling you what the issue is... you're executing outside of an MVC application and for that you would need to post a new question. If I've been of help I'd appreciate if you mark the question answered. Best of luck

Comment: If you're not going to take the advice given to you why ask it

Comment: I am taking the your advice but i am waiting for your example on how actually the changes can be done because you told you will provide the example. and i am not sure  about your solution on changing the  
`HierarchicalLifetimeManager()` to `PerRequestLifetimeManager()`
because it is producing the another error on my code.